# loop checking checking in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have multiple files to upload in a PHP page. Two of them are required field in that. To check that validation I wrote a JS. In my JS, the file types 1 & 2 are required types. Here `count` is the number of files to upload.

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    if (file_type == 1 || file_type == 2) {
        found1++;
    }
}
```

When the value of `found1` becomes `2` the form submission will done. But here a problem is that the required field '1' is uploaded twice the flag value become `2` and the form submission will done. My requirement is '1' & '2' must include in form submission. How to solve this?

Comment: You have lacking information on why the first file type is uploaded twice. Please grace us with more information.

Comment: you can check whether the required field file is uploaded seperately, can't you?

Comment: there is provision to upload any type of file at any number

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but there should be better ways.

```
var file1Uploaded,file2Uploaded = false
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            if (file_type == 1) {
                file1Uploaded=true;
            }
            else if(file_type == 2){
                file2Uploaded=true;
            }
        }
```

check

```
    if(file1Uploaded && file2Uploaded){//submit form}
```

Comment: if i alert two types after uploading two file types ..the loop exists in second only.ie in file2Uploaded alert